# How do I get just the month as a value in SAS from a given date

Tags: date, sas

I got a specific date ('05may2017') and a table with dates. I want to sort the data, more specific by picking from the month may, there is no other date in the data from may. But if I didn't know the exact date I could not sort the data by the date.

My question goes on: I want to pick the month and year 'May2017', and sort the data by the month and year 'may2017'.

How can I drop the day?

Best regards,
Norbit

Comment: I don't think your terminology is sufficiently clear.  You're using "pick" and "sort" in ways that I don't think are the standard meanings for those words.  What are you doing here in the first place - are you producing a report (PROC FREQ or something), are you producing a filtered dataset with just rows from the date you want, are you actually sorting by date (in which case I don't understand how the specific date matters, unless you mean that you want to sort that value to the top somehow?), or something else?

Comment: You also need to very clearly state the type of variable you have. If it's a numeric variable with a date format (date9) then you can use the standard MONTH/YEAR/DAY functions. But if it's character you first need to convert it to a SAS date.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you want to filter data to ONLY dates in the month of May and the year of 2017.  Then you want to sort those results.

Use `PROC SORT` with a where filter on the input table:

```
proc sort data=have(where=('31MAY2017'd >= date_var >= '01MAY2017'd)) out=want;
by date_var;
run;
```

This limits the rows going into the sort to be between the start and end of May 2017.  The output is sorted by date.

This assumes your data are in a table called `have` and your date variable is named `date_var`.  It also assumes you date is stored as a date and not a string.  Obviously, make changes as needed.